# Failed to passing parameters to notepad.exe using Javascript

Tags: javascript, notepad

I am launching `notepad.exe` using javascript and passing parameters to it using following script. It launches `notepad.exe` but prompts that `Hello World.txt does not exists. Do you want to create?`

Any Idea/Suggestion to pass parameter and make `notepad.exe` written with `Hello World`

```
function passParam()
{
try{
    //get brwosers details
    var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/false || !!document.documentMode;

    if(isIE == true)
    {
        var oShell = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");

        var filePath = "C:\\Windows";
        var fileName = "notepad.exe";
        var commandParms = "Hello World!";

        oShell.ShellExecute(fileName,commandParms,filePath,"open","1");

        return;
    }
    alert("Please use only IE to launch navigator.");   
}
catch(e){
alert("Error:"+e.message);}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The command line argument of `notepad.exe` is a filename to open, not the initial contents of the notepad. You have to write a file to the disk and open notepad pointing to it.

Comment: Gotcha!! Is there any possibilities to pass arguments??

Comment: No, there is not. The only way is that I have written, creating a file and opening that. Or you could fill it after open with winapi like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31021002/open-new-notepad-exe-and-write-content-to-it